# Cast RDD Column to Float

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I have just loaded the `ratings` data from http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip as RDDs in pySpark. I wanted to cast the ratings column to `float`. How should I do it?

I tried using a `lambda` function inside the `map` but it didn't work as I expected.

Below is the code I tried.

```
path_data = "/ml-latest-small"
ratingsFile = sc.textFile(path_data + "/ratings.csv")

ratingsFile_2 = ratingsFile.map(lambda x: x.split(","))

header = ratingsFile_2.first()

ratingsFile_3 = ratingsFile_2.filter(lambda x: x != header)

ratingsFile_4 = ratingsFile_3.map(lambda x: float(x[2])

ratingsFile_4.take(6)
```

I'm getting

`[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0]`

instead of

```
[['1', '1', 4.0, '964982703'],
 ['1', '3', 4.0, '964981247'],
 ['1', '6', 4.0, '964982224'],
 ['1', '47', 5.0, '964983815'],
 ['1', '50', 5.0, '964982931'],
 ['1', '70', 3.0, '964982400']]
```

Comment: Because you only kept one column in your `map`. You probably want: `ratingsFile_3.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], float(x[2]), x[3]) )`

Comment: Thank you pault!